# How can I share my code on some web from where it can be down loaded?

Tags: code-sharing

I need to make available my code for some reviewers to be downloaded from web. How can I do that & through which website. I need to put all files & installation instructions using which they can install my app from link that I give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always zip it and host it somewhere online for downloading. I'm sure anyone opening the archive will read the README file first so you can put your instructions there.

Comment: Click on the downloads button -> click on the "Create New Release" link -> Fill in the form -> Add your source code files (or just the zip file) to the "available downloads" section. After you've done that, you'll need to Click the "Publish this Project" button

Answer (score 1):

Check out :
http://Codeplex.com

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com